# VBA Imprimir pelo PDFCreator

Tags: vba, pdf, excel-vba

estou tentando imprimir um arquivo do IE pelo PDFCreator, em minhas pesquisas não consegui localizar uma forma em VBA para realizar este processo, ate achei um algoritmo que diz fazer isso, porem não consegui resolver um problema com o WshNetwork, ele me da como Erro de compilação, como tipo não definido pelo usuário. Gostaria de saber se alguém conhece uma forma de se trabalhar com o PDFCreator pelo vba, fazer com que imprima uma pagina, utilizando o programa, por completo, ou seja, aonde eu consiga determinar o nome do arquivo e colocar o caminho, caso não seja possível, alguma coisa que me de uma ponto ou algo assim.

Comment: Para automações com programas, janelas, botões. Eu utilizo o script do [AutoIt](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/). Em que um script do autoit é criado e depois pode ser chamado pelo VBA. Há formas complexas de trabalhar com softwares não windows no VBA, uma delas é importar bibliotecas .dll, porém acho o AutoIT mais fácil para aplicações específicas

Comment: @danieltakeshi eu consegui resolver este problema da forma a seguir, mas agradeço profundamento sua dica e irei guarda para aplicações futuras. =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui achar a resposta em outro fórum, ao qual agora não me lembro e  infelizmente não posso dar credito ao autor.

Segue a forma ao qual eu consegui realizar todo o procedimento em segundo plano.

```
'- atribui nome do documento e o caminho para download as devidas variaveis
sPDFNome = "name"
sPDFPath = "c:\teste" & contrato & Application.PathSeparator

'seta a variavel e cria o objeto do pdf creator
Set pdfjob = CreateObject("PDFCreator.clsPDFCreator")

'- verifica se o programa esta aberto - caso esteja ele vai mandar uma mensagem para e finalizar a sub
'- caso nao esteja -
With pdfjob
    If .cStart("/NOProcessingAtStartup") = False Then
        MsgBox "Programa Aberto", vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "prtPDFCreator"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    .cOption("UseAutosave") = 1
    .cOption("UseAutosaveDirectory") = 1
    .cOption("AutosaveDirectory") = sPDFPath
    .cOption("AutosaveFilename") = sPDFNome
    .cOption("AutosaveFormat") = 0 '0 = pdf
    .cClearCache

End With

'- enviar comando para imprimir
'ie.PrintOut copies:=1, ActivePrinter:="PDFCreator"
ie.ExecWB 6, 2, "", ""

'- verifica se o arquivo derminou de ser impresso
Do Until pdfjob.cCountOfPrintjobs = 1
    DoEvents
Loop

pdfjob.cPrinterStop = False

'- verifica se tem algum arquivo na lista de impressao
Do Until pdfjob.cCountOfPrintjobs = 0
    DoEvents
Loop

'- fechar a impressa
pdfjob.cClose

'- larga o objeto
Set pdfjob = Nothing
```